# Extending Coordinate Transformation in Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, coordinate-systems

I have been trying to teach myself general relativity, and I come from a background in mathematics, but I am having a difficult time understanding a particular math fact my book is using. The author is trying to develop the field equations for free space, and starts by proving *every point* $P$ *has a local coordinate system on some neighborhood where the metric is Lorentzian*, using the convention that the metric would be $(+,-,-,-)$. I have no problem with his derivation of this, and he claims he can use this result to prove that, in mass free space, *there exists a global coordinate system with a Lorentz metric*.

My issue is with this claim and proof. We suppose that given two points $P_0$ and $P_1$, their neighborhoods $U_{P_0}$ and $U_{P_1}$ with Lorentz metrics overlap. Let $x$ be the coordinate system for $U_{P_0}$ and $\bar{x}$ be the coordinate system for $U_{P_1}$. The Jacobian matrix of the transformation is

$$J^\mu_{\;\;\nu}=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}$$

If the Lorentz metric is written as a matrix $G=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$, then the transformation takes the form

$$G=JGJ^T$$

as a matrix equation. This proves that at every point in the overlapping region the Jacobian matrix is a matrix of the Lorentz group, which makes sense. The next part is the part where I am struggling, where he says that since the two coordinate systems only differ by a Lorentz Matrix, we can transform one coordinate system (say the barred system) by this Lorentz matrix and our new Jacobian matrix $J$ would be the identity matrix, so the coordinates are at most a displacement. While I agree that this would work, my argument is that the Lorentz matrix $J$ is variable, and so it is not as simple as simply applying a Lorentz matrix to the coordinates, because it is unclear if a single transformation would apply everywhere. Moreover, this would only apply on the overlapping region, where the Jacobian is defined, and not the entire space of both neighborhoods.

Plainly, I am wondering that if $J$ is a Jacobian matrix and a Lorentz matrix, then it must be constant. If the matrix was constant, then this would solve the problem, since we could apply it everywhere on one region and not worry about how it connects together in its extension.

I may be off base in this claim (or if there is even a problem to begin with) but I was hoping that someone could clear this issue up for me. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: While I was of course interested in this approach, in reality, I am only seeking a proof to this claim: **if the Riemann Tensor** $R^\alpha_{\;\mu\beta\gamma}$ **is identically zero, there exists a global  coordinate system with Lorentzian metric**. This must be done as a first principles result, as we are trying to derive the field equations from this. If anyone has another approach to demonstrating this, that is fine as well.

Comment: Hi and welcome to PSE!  Finally someone with a non-empty profile :-) Please cite the book you are reading from. At first sight the book's statement seems wrong to me.

Comment: @magma Hey there! I'm using quite an old book called __Introduction to General Relativity__ by Alder, Bazin, and Schiffer. The actual quote is, "We thus see that $A$ and $B$ (the transformations to another coordinate system) can differ only by a Lorentz rotation at each point......We then have one transformation which puts the metric in the form [Lorentz] in the combined neighborhoods...", which is  on page 155, if you're interested.

Comment: As an additional point, I think you have to add the hypothesis that the topology of spacetime is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Otherwise you can have counterexamples like a torus, because of the simple fact that they don't have a global coordinate system.

Comment: @Javier I totally agree to that. The topology must be that of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The thinking I had was that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lindelof Space, so we can find a countable collection of neighborhoods to combine together to form the whole space. The only hiccup is showing I can combine two together.